# Responsive scroll background issue

Tags: html, css-tables

I have the following CSS, trying to make a responsive table-like design.

```
.table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table__row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.table__column {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .54rem 1.05rem;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abuer473/

The problem is that when a user scrolls to the right, the background gets lost. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding background to the columns of every even numbered row:-

**css:**

```
.table__row:nth-child(2n) > .table__column {
  background: #AAA;
}
```

or else you could write

**css:**

```
.table__row:nth-child(even) > .table__column {
  background: #AAA;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/abuer473/11/)

Comment: Sam, why do you think its not working on `table__row`? Do you think nested `display:flex` can be the reason?

Comment: Mm.. I also don't understand this behavior o.O  It seems the background doesn't get applied beyond the boundaries of its parent container.