# Applying background to flex children does not work properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following code

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: red;
}
.grand-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .54rem 1.05rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">a</div>
    <div class="grand-child">b</div>
    <div class="grand-child">c</div>
    <div class="grand-child">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n980bheu/1/)**

**Problem:**
When a background is applied to the class `.children`, the background is not overflowed content (When scrolling through x axis). I want to keep the scrollability as it is while applying the background only to `.children` class. If that is not possible what is the reason?

I had this question while answering [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344940/responsive-scroll-background-issue/51345056#51345056). Though I managed to provide a fix for the issue this specific problem still remains

Comment: please explain the question well...what is the output you would like to have?

Comment: Hi @DreamHunter Please run the snippet and scroll through x-axis you will see the red background is not covering the whole `.children` div. I want to know why

Answer (score 1):

it just because of the `flex-shrink: 0`; property on your `grand-chil`d class.please remove that if you want to align your all grand-childs inside the child class.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: red;
  width:1200px;
}
.grand-child {
  /*flex-shrink: 0;*/
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .54rem 1.05rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">a</div>
    <div class="grand-child">b</div>
    <div class="grand-child">c</div>
    <div class="grand-child">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to keep scrolling as it is and apply the background too, is it possible?

Comment: yes it's,but for that you need to give the exact width to your parent element (child),i'm edited the snippet according with your criteria..hopes it will help you.

Comment: 300px x 4 (grand-childs total width) =1200px

Answer (score 0):

let's check that code.

https://jsfiddle.net/2cuqL1f3/7/

css:

```
.child {
  background: red;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.grand-child {

  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark :) But this is not what i am expecting